# illustrator CS6 dialogue box "color conflict" doesn't pop up

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Where can I set the illustrator CS6 dialogue box "color conflict" to pup up?  When I paste color shapes havig the same color name, the color change without any warning or a dialogue box

Answer (score 1):

**Mac**: Illustrator -> Preferences -> General or Apple + K. Click the "Reset All Warnings Dialogs" button.

**Windows**: Edit -> Preferences -> General. Click the "Reset All Warnings Dialogs" button.

Comment: I work on a Mac.  I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't seems to work for me.  I've even closed and re-opened Illustrator after I did the selection "reset all warnings Dialogs" and it's still not working...  :-(

Comment: @Nancy see relevant thread: [Swatch Conflict](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55276/swatch-conflict). Based on the answers in that thread, this is not a global settings and the pop up should happen in new documents. Besides that you can always reset all preferences to default.

Comment: AndrewH, I've read this before.  It didn't solve the problem for me.  I still dont understand how come we dont have the pop-up window...  Me and my co-worker are in the same situation with Illustrator CS6 (on 2 different computers).  In the previous versions, it was active but now, it's not anymore.  I don't know what to do with this except changing colours names before copying them to be paste in the other document (that's a pain).

Comment: @Nancy I am not sure then, because this is troubleshooting for a program and not necessarily about graphic design. I would advise you to visit the [Adobe Illustrator forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator)